# Grey out entire site

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to grey out my entire set when someone drags in a file to upload. The event for dragging and actually activating the grey is working properly, but it doesn't work everywhere.

When you hover certain parts of the site the grey disappear, particulary in the #menu- and the #dragndrop-area. I understand this is a position issue but I haven't managed to find a good fix for it yet. I've tried using z-index to no avail.

CSS:

```
#menu {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 23px;
    padding-top: 7px;
}
#dragndrop {
    background-image: url(../img/dragndrop.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 733px;
    height: 71px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -366.5px;
    margin-top: -35.5px;
}

#filedrag {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

#filedrag.hover {
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="filedrag">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php" id="menu-upload">Upload</a></li>
                    <li><a href="search.php" id="menu-search">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000000" />    
        </form>
        <script src="filedrag.js"></script>

        <div id="dragndrop">
                <div id="text-box">
                test
                </div>
        </div></div>
```

Here I'm trying to wrap the whole site in #filedrag but it doesn't work. Any ideas? It covers teh site but whenever I hover over the logo or the menu it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try `z-index`'ing everything to be beneath the area that greys out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the whole site in #filedrag. Instead have it as an absolute div just sitting as a direct child of  as follows:

```
...
<div id="filedrag"></div>
</body>
```

Then just have it hide and show with your Javascript.

The key is to probably separate the droppable zone and the 100% overlay div.

Comment: If I do this I don't even get a grey zone anymore. How would I separate them?